# Run PHP script forever for push notifications on HostGator

Tags: php, ios, linux, push-notification

I have a PHP script I need to run that has an infinite loop. It is used to connect to Apple's push notification services then go through our push queue to push out notifications as they come in.

My question is: How do I run a PHP script so that it never times out/ turns off? Is this even the proper way of going about this or should I be doing it another way?

I have HostGator with cPanel. I also have access to the root through Putty using the Linux Command Line.

What I've tried:
1.) I tried running the script through the Linux command prompt in the background. This worked but eventually stopped (I'm guessing it timed out?)
2.) I researched "Cron Jobs" but this seems to call the script every x minutes.

I want something that is constantly running and never times out.

Comment: One way is to call [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), but I would rather a script is run everytime something is added to the push queue. I am not sure you can run a PHP-script as a server in the background that way.

Comment: He can, I used some daemons more that 100 days without problems and restarts, but I recommend use some library, because he will get many problems which improved in completed solutions

Comment: Thanks guys, I need this script to run forever. It's pushing out chat notifications for an iOS app. I'm looking into phpdaemon now based on all of your replies but can't figure out how to actually use it as the documentation is in a different language :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want perform php like daemon you should:

- Unlink from console;
- Set [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) to 0;
- Maybe you want create asynchronous script;
- Maybe you will want perform different programs;
- etc.

Also you will get many problems with stop process, check status, etc.

I recommend use something like PHPDaemon [1](http://daemon.io/), [2](https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon) (maybe [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/)?) library and don't think about problems and use something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), if your daemons will crash, or stuck it will restart your daemons automatically.

Comment: PHPDaemon looks like the answer but I can't figure out how to actually use it. All of the documentation is in a different language.

Comment: I added some additional libraries, if you will have questions about those libraries, you can ask, or search some other libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Cron** to run a script every minute.

```
php -f /home/your_username/public_html/script.php
```

You can read the [documentation from cPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs) to know how to use in your server.

Comment: Thanks but it's pushing out chat messages so I can't wait a whole minute

Comment: You could make your script run in loop for this minute, this way you could have lots of 1 minute loops.

Comment: I believe if you're constantly connecting to the Apple APNS it will block us out thinking it is a DDOS attack? That's why once my PHP script gets the connections it reuses it until it loses connection then reconnects. If I ran the script every minute, I would be reconnecting every minute.

Comment: Understood, let us know how will you resolve this, and if you can install php daemon on hostgator.